# Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_soap.dll' from sessionclean cron

Tags: 16.04, cron, php7

> HP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_soap.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_soap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

I just noticed I am getting this warning with the sessionclean cron.
I have php7 installed on ubuntu 16.04.

How can I resolve this error? Is my sessionclean old in trying to use dlls?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a Windows library (a DLL) on a Linux system. DLLs don't work on Linux (apart from emulating with Wine, developing with Mono or such). Additionally, the .dll file you're referencing in your config isn't even there ;)

You need the corresponding .so library, which should be supplied by the package `php7.0-soap`. In general, many PHP modules can be found in their respective packages, like `php7.0-mysql`, `php7.0-intl` or `php7.0-cgi`.

Comment: Alright, so I dont know why the sessionclean cron exists, or how exactly its trying to use these dlls? 
But as far as the .so libraries I have those installed already... so if this sessionclean routine is needed then how can I relink it to the php7.0-soap

Answer (score 0):

the DLL files are for windows and not work in linux distributions
vice versa of DLL files in php for linux is .so files

so at first you need to download php_soap.so and put it in a specific directory
then edit your php.ini file and search about ***extension=bz2*** and add following line under it:

***extension=/directory/to/php_soap/file/php_soap.so***